# What is the Content Area ID?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Content Area ID is not listed as a [property of a ContentArea](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/contentarea/). What is it? The External Key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContentArea ID is a unique identification and it will automatically generate (always integer number) once content area created. You can get the ContentArea ID by clicking Content Properties option and same ID will use in `AmpScript/APIAmpScript/SSJS` to retrieve the ContentArea in `Email/Template/LandingPage/CloudPage`.

Also, it's not a External Key and you can use the ID properties to get the ContentArea details like below.

```
<script type="text/javaScript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var results = ContentAreaObj.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"176240"});
    Write(Stringify(results));
</script>
```